# Is "freq" in result.describe() counting True or False?

Tags: python, finance

I am learning Python and I have question regarding bool. The code listed below gives me the freq is this the number of True or the number of False? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
result = BD["75 prev "] == BD['Low']
result.describe()
```

```
count      2941
unique        2
top       False
freq       2931
dtype: object
```

Comment: Is `BD` a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Note that changing from backticks to block formatting (four spaces per line, as created by selecting a block and clicking the `{}` button) not only made the formatting a bit prettier (with the background extending across the line), but also enabled syntax highlighting for the code.

Comment: ...speaking to content -- a [mcve] would answer Aran-Fey's question, and others, by providing enough code to let someone actually generate the result at hand (even if on a reduced/minimal dataset) themselves.

Comment: The docs say: *For object data (e.g. strings or timestamps), the result’s index will include count, unique, top, and freq. The top is the most common value. The freq is the most common value’s frequency. Timestamps also include the first and last items.* You could try a check yourself by doing `result.value_counts()`...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you!!! I have been struggling to get the formatting right on StackOverflow. I will follow this advice!

Comment: @JonClements Thank you so much for that code. I have asked half a dozen people on how to get exactly that!!! Thank you ninja dog!

Answer (score 4):

The `freq` is tied to the `top` immediately above it. `top` is the most frequent element, `freq` is how many times that most frequent element was seen.

So in your case, `False` was the most frequent, appearing `2931` times, which means `10` values were non-`False` (`True` in this case).